# Can search permission be controlled with BlueSpice extension to MediaWiki?

Tags: search, mediawiki, permissions

The BlueSpice extension to MediaWiki introduces permissions control with the introduction of the `Namespace manager` administration tool.  Each namespace can be set to be "Search by default" or not.  However, regardless of this setting, the user can always search everything.

Presently, this allows a user to see page names for pages that they do not have read permission but which match their search keywords.  Is there another control in the `Permissions manager` admin tool so that namespaces can only be searched if the user is in a group with permission to see (read) a namespace?

Comment: See [How to restrict read permission of a namespace in mediawiki](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27101836/323407).